# Miller-Rabin Primality test fails for large numbers

Tags: c#, primes, prime-factoring

After studying other SO answers related to the Miller-Rabin test for primality, I implemented a version in C#, but it begins to occasionally fail somewhere in the region of three billion, and by the time it gets to four billion, it stops recognizing any primes. I suspect that I am suffering overflow, but cannot figure out where. My goal is to get this to work for any value in the range 0 <= n <= 2^63 - 1.

I created a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3F7P97

Among the ideas I tried were:

1. Using precalculated bases 2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022 advertised as working well for numbers less than 2^64 from this website: http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/
   This was recommended by an answerer of this question: [Miller Rabin Primality test accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096332/miller-rabin-primality-test-accuracy)
2. Writing an overflow resistant power-mod function for computing a^b mod n.
3. Writing an overflow resistant multiplication function for computing a*b mod n (using Russian peasant algorithm).

Here is the code from the fiddle as of the time I created this question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// AUTHOR: Paul A. Chernoch
//
// Purpose: Use Rabin-Miller algorithm to test if numbers are prime.
// Problem: Somewhere between 2 billion and 4,194,304,903 it stops working and always says the number is not prime.
// Hypothesis: The code should work for all 64-bit values, but suspiciously breaks near the maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer.
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // These cases always succeed.
        for (long n = 0; n < 20; n++)
        {
            TestRabinMiller(n);
        }

        TestRabinMiller(2000000011L);
        TestRabinMiller(2147483647L); // 2^31 - 1 is prime.
        TestRabinMiller(2147483659L); // 2^31 + 11 is prime.

        // These cases fail! I think it has to do with overflow on a multiplication or something.

        TestRabinMiller(3042000007L); // Sometimes succeeds, sometimes fails
        TestRabinMiller(3043000003L); // Sometimes succeeds, sometimes fails
        TestRabinMiller(3045000031L); // Sometimes succeeds, sometimes fails
        TestRabinMiller(4000000007L); // Always fails
        TestRabinMiller(4194304903L); // Always fails
        TestRabinMiller(4294967291L); // Always fails
        TestRabinMiller(4294967311L); // Always fails
    }

    public static void TestRabinMiller(long n)
    {
        var factors = BuggyCode.RabinMiller.Factor(n);
        var expectedIsPrime = factors.Count() == 1 && n >= 2;
        var expectedWords = expectedIsPrime ? "IS A PRIME.  " : "IS NOT PRIME.";
        var actualIsPrime = BuggyCode.RabinMiller.IsPrime(n,20);
        var actualWords = actualIsPrime ? "IS A PRIME.  " : "IS NOT PRIME.";
        var results = actualIsPrime == expectedIsPrime ? "SUCCEEDED." : "FAILED.   ";
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Test of RabinMiller {0} It says that {1} {2} In reality, the number {1} {3}", results, n, actualWords, expectedWords));
    }
}

namespace BuggyCode
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Test if a number is prime using the Rabin-Miller primality test.
    /// </summary>
    public class RabinMiller
    {
        private static HashSet<long> KnownPrimes = new HashSet<long>()
        {
            2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
            31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
            73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 
            127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 
            179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 
            233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 
            283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
            353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 
            419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 
            467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 
            547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 
            607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 
            661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 
            739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 
            811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 
            877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 
            947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 
            1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 
            1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 
            1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 
            1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 
            1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 
            1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 
            1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 
            1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 
            1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 
            1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 
            1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 
            1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 
            1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 
            1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 
            2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 
            2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 
            2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 
            2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 
            2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 
            2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 
            2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 
            2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 
            2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 
            2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 
            2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 
            2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 
            3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 
            3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 
            3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 
            3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 
            3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 
            3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 
            3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 
            3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 
            3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 
            3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 
            3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 
            3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 
            4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 
            4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 
            4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 
            4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 
            4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 
            4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 
            4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 
            4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 
            4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 
            4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 
            4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 
            4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999, 5003, 
            5009, 5011, 5021, 5023, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 
            5099, 5101, 5107, 5113, 5119, 5147, 5153, 5167, 5171, 5179, 
            5189, 5197, 5209, 5227, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 
            5281, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5333, 5347, 5351, 5381, 5387, 
            5393, 5399, 5407, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5441, 5443, 
            5449, 5471, 5477, 5479, 5483, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5521, 
            5527, 5531, 5557, 5563, 5569, 5573, 5581, 5591, 5623, 5639, 
            5641, 5647, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5659, 5669, 5683, 5689, 5693, 
            5701, 5711, 5717, 5737, 5741, 5743, 5749, 5779, 5783, 5791, 
            5801, 5807, 5813, 5821, 5827, 5839, 5843, 5849, 5851, 5857, 
            5861, 5867, 5869, 5879, 5881, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5939, 
            5953, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6011, 6029, 6037, 6043, 6047, 6053, 
            6067, 6073, 6079, 6089, 6091, 6101, 6113, 6121, 6131, 6133, 
            6143, 6151, 6163, 6173, 6197, 6199, 6203, 6211, 6217, 6221, 
            6229, 6247, 6257, 6263, 6269, 6271, 6277, 6287, 6299, 6301, 
            6311, 6317, 6323, 6329, 6337, 6343, 6353, 6359, 6361, 6367, 
            6373, 6379, 6389, 6397, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6451, 6469, 6473, 
            6481, 6491, 6521, 6529, 6547, 6551, 6553, 6563, 6569, 6571, 
            6577, 6581, 6599, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6653, 6659, 6661, 6673, 
            6679, 6689, 6691, 6701, 6703, 6709, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6761, 
            6763, 6779, 6781, 6791, 6793, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6829, 6833, 
            6841, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6871, 6883, 6899, 6907, 6911, 6917, 
            6947, 6949, 6959, 6961, 6967, 6971, 6977, 6983, 6991, 6997, 
            7001, 7013, 7019, 7027, 7039, 7043, 7057, 7069, 7079, 7103, 
            7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7151, 7159, 7177, 7187, 7193, 7207,
            7211, 7213, 7219, 7229, 7237, 7243, 7247, 7253, 7283, 7297, 
            7307, 7309, 7321, 7331, 7333, 7349, 7351, 7369, 7393, 7411, 
            7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7459, 7477, 7481, 7487, 7489, 7499, 
            7507, 7517, 7523, 7529, 7537, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7559, 7561, 
            7573, 7577, 7583, 7589, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7621, 7639, 7643, 
            7649, 7669, 7673, 7681, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7717, 7723, 
            7727, 7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 
            7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919
        };

        private static long MaxKnownPrime { get; set; }

        static RabinMiller()
        {
            MaxKnownPrime = KnownPrimes.Max ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For the deterministic Rabin-Miller test, these are the best bases for numbers below 2^64.
        /// 
        /// See http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/
        /// </summary>
        private static long[] BestRabinMillerBases = new long[] { 2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022 };

        /// <summary>
        /// The smallest prime factor for small numbers.
        /// </summary>
        private static long[] FactorsForSmallNumbers = new long[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 2, 11, 2, 13, 2, 3, 2, 17, 2, 19, 2 };


        /// <summary>
        /// Rabin-Miller primality test.
        /// 
        /// The error rate of false results is (1/4)^k.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="n">Number to test for primality.</param>
        /// <param name="k">Number of different bases to test. 
        /// The higher the number, the more accurate the test and the longer the running time.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if n is prime; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// Note: Zero and one are not considered prime.
        /// </returns>
        public static bool IsPrime(long n, int k)
        {
            if(n < 2)
            {
                return false; // Zero and one are not prime.
            }

            // Speedup for low values that also improves accuracy.
            if (n <= MaxKnownPrime)
                return KnownPrimes.Contains (n);

            foreach(var knownPrime in KnownPrimes)
            {
                if (n % knownPrime == 0) return false;  
            }

            var s = n - 1L;
            while((s & 1L) == 0L)
            {
                s >>= 1;
            }
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                long a;
                if (i < BestRabinMillerBases.Length)
                    a = BestRabinMillerBases [i];
                else // Random choice of base.
                    a = (long)(r.NextDouble() * (n - 1L)) + 1L;
                var temp = s;
                var mod = ModuloPower(a, temp, n);
                while(temp != n - 1L && mod != 1L && mod != n - 1L)
                {
                    mod = RussianPeasant(mod, mod, n);
                    temp = temp << 1;
                }
                if(mod != n - 1L && (temp & 1L) == 0L)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static bool IsPrime(long n) 
        {
            var k = 1;
            var temp = n;
            while (temp > 0L) 
            {
                temp /= 10L;
                k++;
            }
            k = Math.Max (5, k);
            return IsPrime (n, k);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a^b mod n but guard against overflow.
        /// 
        /// Use repeated squarings to reduce the number of operations.
        /// Special case: Assume 0 ^ 0 = 1 to be consistenct with Math.Pow.
        /// 
        /// See https://helloacm.com/compute-powermod-abn/
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">Base to be exponentiated.</param>
        /// <param name="b">The exponent.</param>
        /// <param name="n">Modulus.</param>
        /// <returns>a^b mod n.</returns>
        public static long ModuloPower(long a, long b, long n)
        {
            // return (a^b)%n -> Simple calculation that would often overflow
            // Example: For a^19, there are five squarings, two multipications and seven modulos, instead of 18 multiplications and eighteen modulos
            //     a^19 -> (a^2)^9 * a -> (((a^2)^2)^4 * (a^2)) * a -> ((((a^2)^2)^2)^2 * (a^2)) * a
            if (b == 0L) return 1L;
            if (a == 0L) return 0L;
            if (b == 1L) return a % n;
            var r = ModuloPower (a, b >> 1, n);
            r = RussianPeasant(r, r, n);
            if ((b & 1L) == 1L)
                r = RussianPeasant(r, a, n);
            return r;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Russian peasant multiplication of a*b mod c, which avoids overflow.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">First multiplicand.</param>
        /// <param name="b">Second multiplicand.</param>
        /// <param name="c">Modulus.</param>
        /// <returns>a * b mod c</returns>
        public static long RussianPeasant(long a, long b, long c)
        {
            const long _2_32 = 1L << 32;
            a = Math.Abs (a);
            b = Math.Abs (b);
            if (a < _2_32 && b < _2_32)
                return (a * b % c); // No possibility of overflow.
            if (c < _2_32)
                return (a % c) * (b % c) % c;
            long ret = 0;
            while(b != 0) {
                if((b&1L) != 0L) {
                    ret += a;
                    ret %= c;
                }
                a *= 2;
                a %= c;
                b /= 2;
            }
            return ret;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Slow, exhaustive but simple method of finding prime factors, useful for testing against the more complex methods.
        /// 
        /// Its only speedup is a table of known primes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="n">The number to be factored.</param>
        /// <returns>Prime factors of n, sorted frmo low to high.</returns>
        public static List<long> Factor(long n) 
        {
            var factors = new List<long> ();
            var lowFactor = 2;
            var factorFound = true;
            while (factorFound) 
            {
                if (n <= MaxKnownPrime && KnownPrimes.Contains (n))
                    break;

                factorFound = false;
                var maxFactor = (long) Math.Sqrt (n);
                for (var fac = lowFactor; fac <= maxFactor; fac++) 
                {
                    if (n % fac == 0) 
                    {
                        factors.Add (fac);
                        n /= fac;
                        lowFactor = fac;
                        factorFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            factors.Add (n);
            return factors;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"I suspect that I am suffering overflow"_ -- yes, that seems likely. _"cannot figure out where"_ -- why not? What did you try? Have you stepped through the failed case watching your variables for overflow? Have you compiled your program with checked arithmetic so that it would throw an exception if overflow occurred? Stack Overflow is a good place to get _help_ with debugging; not so great a place to just get someone else to do your debugging for you.

Comment: Tried this: Wrote unit tests for ModuloPower (not shown in my code example) and they all pass. Wrote many units tests for IsPrime - the low numbers pass and the high numbers fail. The fact that tests uniformly succeed for low numbers is the clue that points me to overflow as a problem.

Comment: I am not trying to get someone else to do my debugging for me. After two days and about ten hours of debugging, reading numerous SO posts and several C.S. and mathematics papers, I assure you made every effort to solve my problem without asking for help. That is how I discovered that many C# operations have slightly different definitions from the functions cited in mathematics papers, such as mod versus %, GCD, etc. That research led me to Russian Peasant and the ModPower idea, plus "best" values for base. It is these edge cases that have been killing me, because my intuition is failing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem: RussianPeasant. I did not test every edge case. My overflow limit should have been 2^31, not 2^32, to account for the sign bit. Here is the corrected method:

```
    public static long RussianPeasant(long a, long b, long c)
    {
        const long overflow_limit = 1L << 31;
        a = Math.Abs (a);
        b = Math.Abs (b);
        if (a < overflow_limit && b < overflow_limit)
            return (a * b % c); // No possibility of overflow.
        if (c < overflow_limit)
            return (a % c) * (b % c) % c;
        long ret = 0;
        while(b != 0) {
            if((b&1L) != 0L) {
                ret += a;
                ret %= c;
            }
            a *= 2;
            a %= c;
            b /= 2;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```